# Front-end for editing data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've imported int ELK a lot of our tests CI run data, and Kibana looks great and get the job done.
but I wanted to edit the documents directly in Kibana (for example: adding/edit Notes)

someone have an idea, that doesn't involve tearing Kibana guts for it ? 
(I've thought building a separate django/flask app, but looks like a lot of work, and I'll end up with an ugly app :))

Comment: In my practice it happend to be much simplier to do work with bare Elasticsearch, because hacking into Kibana even looked dangerous. We needed to create our own mapping, and it was almost impossible.

Comment: That what i was looking for, something to edit the data, it would be nice if it could be embedded into kibana