# Make changes in Elastic Search directly using Kibana

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch, crud, kibana

Is is possible to change values(add , delete , update) in Elastic Search using Kibana dashboard. Is it possible to create a plugin on the top of Kibana which uses certain set of apis & queries to make changes in Elastic Search directly from KIbana???

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, even if it were possible. Kibana is about visualizing data, most commonly log data. You shouldn't really manually manipulate it through a visualization tool.

Comment: @Nikolaj,
Is it possible to use Kibana for this purpose of manipulating data talking in terms security & feasiblity

Comment: Not as is. I reckon it'll be too much of a hassle trying to bend Kibana to do data manipulations, compared to just doing it manually with ElasticSearch queries. Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642653/front-end-for-editing-data-in-elasticsearch

Comment: In kibana dashboard it's not possible, but if you using kibana 5 you can do that in dev tools,if you using earlier version of kibana you can use Sense chrome plugin that allow you to perform REST request like add and delete